# I misunderstand win32 (and maybe libc) strtok( )

Tags: c, strtok

In some CGI code, I need to encode rarely-occurring '&', '<', and '>' chars. In the encoding function, I want to get out right away if there are no such chars in the input string. So, at entry, I try to use `strtok( )` to find that out:

```
char *
encode_amp_lt_gt ( char *in ) {
  ...
  if ( NULL == strtok( in, "&<>" )) {
    return in;
  }
  ...
}
```

But, even in the absence of any of the delimiters, `strtok( )` returns a pointer to the first character of `in`.

I expected it to return NULL if no delims in the string.

Is my code wrong, or is my expectation wrong? I don't want to call strchr( ) three times just to eliminate the usual case.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you deal with very, very large text, `strchr` three times ain't gonna kill your performance.

Comment: @zneak has a point on premature optimization, but I'll take it a bit further and ask if you've considered doing this in a higher-level language than C. I know PHP has a library function for encoding special characters and I'd be shocked if it wasn't easy in Perl, Python, and Ruby as well.

Comment: @Jordan Wade -- thanks, next time for sure :-)

Comment: If you are afraid of repeating `strchr`s there is also `strpbrk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is `strpbrk`, not `strtok`. The bigger question is - how is the string that is being returned being allocated when you're replacing things, and how does the calling function know if it should free it or not?

Comment: The expanded, returned string is in a static char[ ] array that's big enough, so I'm ok there, but THANKS for mentioning it. Please always do point out this potential ass-biting (as I know from painful experience) error when you have a chance. Thanks also for mentioning strpbrk( ), I never use it but now I will.

Comment: It took me a while to grok how deep your question is. For this app, the answer is: if the ptr returned to the caller is diff from the ptr the caller passed in, then that ptr has to be free( )ed.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want `strtok` to begin with, as it leaves you no way of figuring what character was eliminated (except if you have a spare copy of the string).

`strtok` is not a straightforward API and is easy to misunderstand.

Quoting the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/):

```
 The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the beginning of
 each subsequent token in the string, after replacing the token itself with
 a NUL character.  When no more tokens remain, a null pointer is returned.
```

Your problem probably means you've fallen to the obscurity of the algorithm. Suppose this string:

```
char* value = "foo < bar & baz > frob";
```

The first time you call `strtok`:

```
char* ptr = strtok(value, "<>&");
```

`strtok` will return you the `value` pointer, **except that** it will have modified the string to this:

```
"foo \0 bar & baz > frob"
```

As you may notice, it changed the `<` to a `NUL`. Now, however, if you use `value`, you'll get `"foo "` since there's a `NUL` in the middle of the way.

Subsequent calls to `strtok` with `NULL` will proceed through the string, until you've reached the end of the string, at which point you'll get `NULL`.

```
char* str = "foo < bar & frob > nicate";
printf("%s\n", strtok(str, "<>&")); // prints "foo "
printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, "<>&")); // prints " bar "
printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, "<>&")); // prints " frob "
printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, "<>&")); // prints " nicate"
assert(strtok(NULL, "<>&") == NULL); // should be true
```

It would be fairly straightforward to write a function that replaces the contents without `strtok`, either dealing with the hard work yourself, or getting help from [`strpbrk`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) and [`strcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's not well explained on the man page. So now I know that strtok( ) will always return non-NULL for a non-empty string.